# Как правильно будет написать предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, падежи, управление, спп

*ЭЦП проставлено сертификатом, на котор**ом** нет заключённого соглашения.*

или

*ЭЦП проставлено сертификатом, на котор**ый** нет заключённого соглашения.*

Comment: Да все предложение какое-то несуразное, если подумать. Впрочем, оно может сойти за высокие материи, неподсильные рядовому клерку. "ЭЦП проставлено сертификатом" скорее надо "сертификат проставленной ЭЦП". Соглашение заключается не на сертификат, а на ФИО, которое уже указывается в сертификате.

Comment: Нет, у меня конкретно вопрос как будет правильней в окончании который или котором, без перестановки слов. Это конкретное предложение. Тут суть не на то, на что заключается договор, а само окончание в предложении

Comment: Если вас не интересует смысл слов, а только грамматика, то корректны оба варианта. Слово "который" не обязано согласовываться в падеже с предметом, который описывает.

Comment: Я знаю смысл предложения, я с этим, работаю и вопрос рабочего характера. В данном случае предложение должно идти в согласии с предметом. А если в согласии, то вероятнее всего окончание - ом, будет правильней и по крайней мере созвучней

Comment: В данном случае не имеет смысла углубляться в смысл слова ЭЦП, даже если так, то ЭЦП и сертификат это одно и тоже, только разных родов. Меня интересует "сертификатом на котором нет" или "сертификатом на который нет".

Comment: И так и так корректно

Comment: но смысл разный получается. Так что о смысле все же придется подумать

Answer (score 3):

Если рассматривать только окончание...

*ЭЦП проставлено сертификатом, на котор**ом** нет заключённого соглашения.*

При такой формулировке рисуется картинка, что сертификат не несёт информации (отметки) о заключённом соглашении.

*ЭЦП проставлено сертификатом, на котор**ый** нет заключённого соглашения.*

Это предложение говорит о том, что сертификат есть, а заключёного соглашения, которое выдаётся на него, нет.